# Log to XML column using log4net

Tags: sql-server, xml, log4net

Is it possible to log to an XML column in SQL Server using the AdoNetAppender in log4net?

I know that I can treat the column as a string and log that way through:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@details" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Details}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

But, I'd rather log using:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@details" />
    <dbType value="Xml" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Details}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.

I'd much rather do the logging using the actual database type instead of taking advantage of the fact that I *could* just use string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DbType.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype(VS.80).aspx) enum value was introduced in .Net 2.0. After closer inspection of [how to use DBType.Xml with ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971534.aspx) it seems that the best way of passing data into an XML column is actually by passing data in as string.

Comment: I was a bit quick and missed the fact that a 2.0 compiled version is indeed included in the log4net distribution.